# mp3 files converting into mpga

Tags: symfony, file-upload

When i upload a .mp3 file with Symfony2 i get a .mpga file uploaded. I used the same code for pictures and it worked like a charm.

I read it could have something to do with the mime types ,but i have to say i am a bit lost on this one!

I don't even know what part of the code i should post for this one . I'll show some of my entity i guess :

```js
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    $this->url = $this->file->guessExtension();
    $this->alt = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {

        return;
    }

    if (null !== $this->tempFilename) {
        $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->id . '.' . $this->tempFilename;
        if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
            unlink($oldFile);
        }
    }

    $this->file->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->id . '.' . $this->url
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first assotiation of the `audio/mpeg` MIME-Type is `mpga` i think the easiest way it to rename the file if you know that you can only upload mp3s.

You can fetch the original name and you can look which name was uploaded. If there is mp3 in the name rename the file.

But thats a known problem. I had the same problem.

Comment: Yup thats a mime issue. I changed the file "vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType" at the line audio/mpeg which solved my issue.

Comment: Changing a file in the vendor folder is a bad idea. Could you suggest a way of doing it properly please?